# Remove a value from a InfoPath 2010 People Picker field programmatically

Tags: c#, infopath

I've seen the question "Assign value to People Picker programatically in Infopath" in SO, but I havent been able to find how to remove a value from a people picker field programmatically in InfoPath 2010.

I have tried setting all three applicable values (DisplayName, AccountId, and AccountType) to "", but that isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove whole Person node instead of setting individual properties to empty values.

Comment: Thanks Alexei, .DeleteSelf() on the person node worked great!